# Is there any way to have Trello Card Cover image be an image URL from the web?

Tags: trello, images

I like using cover images on my card as it makes it easier to visually see the reference.  The issue is I am constantly downloading images and then attaching them to the cards.

Is there anyway I can just put an image URL on a card and have that show up (instead of needing to have the image locally or on Google Drive / Dropbox)?

I want to use this image as the "Cover photo" for the card on the regular board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the true and direct sense, where you might just supply Trello with a URL that points to an externally-hosted cover photo, and Trello might simply display it.

As you correctly state, cover photos for Trello cards currently need to be attached from either "Computer" (local drive), "Google Drive", or "Dropbox".

However, there are several ways that can simplify the process of downloading such an externally-hosted photo to your local drive and then uploading it to Trello in order to make it the cover photo:

1. On the desired card, choose **`Attach File...`**.  For **`Attach From...`**, choose **`Computer`**, and for the file name in the "Upload File" dialog-box, simply paste the desired URL -- say:  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/NASA-Apollo8-Dec24-Earthrise.jpg
2. Or, if you have a browser window opened to view the photo associated with that URL, very simply drag the photo onto the Trello card!

Comment: #2 is the preferred solution, as #1 does not work when the "upload file" dialog box does not offer the option to paste a URL (e.g. on macOS)

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is I am constantly downloading images and then attaching them to the cards.

You can drag an image from another webpage onto a card.  I have only tested this behavior in Chrome.  This would save you the step of downloading the images.

> I want to use this image as the "Cover photo" for the card on the regular board.

Unfortunately, because we resize the images on the server, card covers will be of the image when you uploaded it - changing the image that resides at that url will not do it.

Comment: True, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @jschulenklopper The specifics about wanting to set the cover photo were added after I answered.

Comment: Hi Aaron (I see that you're working for Fog Creek. Compliments on Trello!) Indeed, the post was edited - last line was added - but "I like using cover images on my card as it makes it easier to visually see the reference [...] Is there anyway I can just put an image URL on a card and have that show up" made the intention clear as well. But you're close to Trello development; perhaps you can claim the bounty via a feature push to Trello? :-)

Comment: @jschulenklopper Because we need to do server-side resizing of images for card covers, that would be a pretty difficult feature to add.  I would not expect it to happen any time soon, if at all.  I edited my answer to explain why I thought my answer was useful.

Comment: Upvoted your comment. I was partly joking on that new feature.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible to use an 'external' image referenced by URL as a (changing) cover image. You can include a hyperlink to an image in the card description though, and the actual and current image will show up (instead of the hyperlink).

Copy this into your description, and change the URL to one of your liking:

```
![Logo for Trello Business Class](http://bit.ly/17FHIGQ "Trello Business Class")
```

Comment: Oh, that syntax in the description is Markdown, and Trello supports that by default. More explanation on its syntax can be found at: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img.

Comment: This is correct, but it sounds like the asker is just looking for an easier way to upload images, not to have live updating card covers.

Comment: @jshulenklopper - thanks but that is not my question. my question is how to take that image and make it a card cover?

Comment: No, it isn't yet possible to use an external image (referenced by URL) as cover image.

Comment: @IanHenry, no, (s)he was asking how to make a-not-uploaded-image appear as the card cover.

Comment: @jschulenklopper Where is that specified? I don't see any indication that they're looking for live-updating card covers, just that downloading and then uploading images a lot is annoying. Why do you think it's the same image? In either case, this answer is correct, so I'm not sure who's downvoting you.

Comment: @IanHenry, it is infered from "I like using cover images on my card as it makes it easier to visually see the reference. [...] Is there anyway I can just put an image URL on a card and have that show up? [...] I want to use this image as the "Cover photo" for the card on the regular board." and "my question is how to take that image and make it a card cover?"

Comment: @IanHenry, the implication of live-updating card covers is secondary (and would be an additional feature if Trello allowed it), but not directy her/his question. Including a reference to an image in the description (instead of uploading the image to the card) will result a live-updating image though.